# php://input not catching the request body

Tags: php, api, rest

I build a rest api and I have it running on my mac.  When I moved to the code to windows, for some reason the `php://input` is always blank, even when I add a payload to the request body.

1. I am not accessing the `php://input` stream more than once.
2. The same code is up and running on my mac apache2.2 php5.5.6
3. Doesn't work on apache2.4, php 5.5.6 on windows

I have read that the php directive `allow_file_open` must be true in php.ini for `php://input` to work.  It is already set to true.

this is the how I am grabbing the input stream (the json string passed to the api in the request body)

```
file_get_contents('php://input')
```

Any ideas on why mac likes it but windows doesn't?